# Trouble logging into ssh

Tags: ssh, login

I FINALLY received a 27W power supply yesterday and thought I would use it to fire up an RPi 5.
Igave the same host name as the RP4 I used previously, flashed the image and switched it on and tried to ssh into the pi....  I was unsucessful, with the following error being returned....

ozjoh@192.168.20.9: Permission denied (publickey,password).

How do I fix this ??

Cheers

Ozjohnno

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Use the RPI imager it can add an id for you and activate SSH with a password or with a public key.

Comment: Welcome.  Please *edit into the question* the output from running ssh with `-v`.